# In openFileOutput Android, NullPointerException

Tags: android

NullPointerException occurs from openFileOutput.
context.getPackageName() = android, This code is framework.
I don't know this problem, context or anything...
Can anyone help me please?

-use to contacts app

02-16 02:06:42.449: I/VCardImport(2255): vCard cache thread starts running.

02-16 02:06:42.449: E/VCardImport(2255): filename : import_tmp_0.vcf

02-16 02:06:42.449: E/VCardImport(2255): file : /data/data/com.android.contacts/files/import_tmp_0.vcf

-My source, framework

02-16 01:11:00.525: E/PstContactCreator(549): filename : import_tmp_0.vcf

02-16 01:11:00.525: W/ApplicationContext(549): Unable to create files directory files

02-16 01:11:00.525: E/PstContactCreator(549): file : import_tmp_0.vcf

My source's context is 'android', when I use functions which is getFileStreamPath, openFileOutput, I cannot create file. I think the context cause the problem. I want to know  what cause the problem and how to solve the problem.
context.getFileStreamPath(filename);
context.openFileOutput(filename, Context.MODE_PRIVATE).getChannel();

private Uri copyTo(final Uri sourceUri, String filename) throws IOException {

```
    Log.i(LOG_TAG, String.format("Copy a Uri to app local storage (%s -> %s)",
            sourceUri, filename));
    final Context context = mContext.get();
    final ContentResolver resolver = context.getContentResolver();
    ReadableByteChannel inputChannel = null;
    WritableByteChannel outputChannel = null;
    Uri destUri = null;
    try {
        inputChannel = Channels.newChannel(resolver.openInputStream(sourceUri));
        destUri = Uri.parse(context.getFileStreamPath(filename).toURI().toString());
        outputChannel = context.**openFileOutput**(filename, Context.MODE_PRIVATE).getChannel();

        final ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(8192);

        while (inputChannel.read(buffer) != -1) {
            buffer.flip();
            outputChannel.write(buffer);
            buffer.compact();
        }

        buffer.flip();

        while (buffer.hasRemaining()) {
            outputChannel.write(buffer);
        }

    } finally {
        if (inputChannel != null) {
            try {
                inputChannel.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.w(LOG_TAG, "Failed to close inputChannel.");
            }
        }
        if (outputChannel != null) {
            try {
                outputChannel.close();
            } catch(IOException e) {
                Log.w(LOG_TAG, "Failed to close outputChannel");
            }
        }
    }
    return destUri;
}
```

02-16 01:11:00.455: I/PstManagerService(549): onsetrecordcmd start

02-16 01:11:00.455: I/PstManagerService(549): f.exists

02-16 01:11:00.455: I/PstManagerService(549): after creteNewFile

02-16 01:11:00.465: W/PstContactCreator(549): pst contact start!

02-16 01:11:00.465: E/PstContactCreator(549): filename : import_tmp_0.vcf

02-16 01:11:00.465: W/ApplicationContext(549): Unable to create files directory files

02-16 01:11:00.475: E/PstContactCreator(549): file : import_tmp_0.vcf

02-16 01:11:00.475: I/PstContactCreator(549): Copy a Uri to app local storage 
(file:///cache/pst_contact_r.tmp -> import_tmp_0.vcf)

02-16 01:11:00.475: I/PstContactCreator(549): dcshin 111

02-16 01:11:00.475: E/PstContactCreator(549): inputChannel : 
java.nio.channels.Channels$InputStreamChannel@419ca7a8

02-16 01:11:00.475: I/PstContactCreator(549): dcshin 222

02-16 01:11:00.485: W/ApplicationContext(549): Unable to create files directory files

02-16 01:11:00.495: E/PstContactCreator(549): destUri : file:/import_tmp_0.vcf

02-16 01:11:00.495: I/PstContactCreator(549): dcshin 333

02-16 01:11:00.495: E/PstContactCreator(549): getPackageName : android

02-16 01:11:00.495: E/PstContactCreator(549): getPackageCodePath : null

02-16 01:11:00.505: E/PstContactCreator(549): getPackageResourcePath : null

02-16 01:11:00.505: W/ApplicationContext(549): Unable to create files directory files

02-16 01:11:00.505: E/PstContactCreator(549): java.lang.NullPointerException

02-16 01:11:00.505: I/PstContactCreator(549): Finished caching vCard.

02-16 01:11:00.515: I/PstManagerService(549): onsetrecordcmd start

02-16 01:11:00.515: I/PstManagerService(549): f.exists

02-16 01:11:00.515: I/PstManagerService(549): after creteNewFile

02-16 01:11:00.525: W/PstContactCreator(549): pst contact start!

02-16 01:11:00.525: E/PstContactCreator(549): filename : import_tmp_0.vcf

02-16 01:11:00.525: W/ApplicationContext(549): Unable to create files directory files

02-16 01:11:00.525: E/PstContactCreator(549): file : import_tmp_0.vcf

02-16 01:11:00.525: I/PstContactCreator(549): Copy a Uri to app local storage 
(file:///cache/pst_contact_r.tmp -> import_tmp_0.vcf)

02-16 01:11:00.525: I/PstContactCreator(549): dcshin 111

02-16 01:11:00.525: E/PstContactCreator(549): inputChannel : 
java.nio.channels.Channels$InputStreamChannel@419b0018

02-16 01:11:00.525: I/PstContactCreator(549): dcshin 222

02-16 01:11:00.525: W/ApplicationContext(549): Unable to create files directory files

02-16 01:11:00.525: E/ThermalDaemon(2916): Maximum CPU[1] frequency 918000 KHz

02-16 01:11:00.525: E/PstContactCreator(549): destUri : file:/import_tmp_0.vcf

02-16 01:11:00.525: I/PstContactCreator(549): dcshin 333

02-16 01:11:00.525: E/PstContactCreator(549): getPackageName : android

02-16 01:11:00.525: E/PstContactCreator(549): getPackageCodePath : null

02-16 01:11:00.525: E/PstContactCreator(549): getPackageResourcePath : null

02-16 01:11:00.525: W/ApplicationContext(549): Unable to create files directory files

02-16 01:11:00.525: E/PstContactCreator(549): java.lang.NullPointerException

02-16 01:11:00.525: I/PstContactCreator(549): Finished caching vCard.

02-16 01:11:00.535: I/PstManagerService(549): onsetrecordcmd start

02-16 01:11:00.535: I/PstManagerService(549): f.exists

02-16 01:11:00.535: I/PstManagerService(549): after creteNewFile

02-16 01:11:00.535: W/PstContactCreator(549): pst contact start!

02-16 01:11:00.535: E/PstContactCreator(549): filename : import_tmp_0.vcf

02-16 01:11:00.535: W/ApplicationContext(549): Unable to create files directory files

02-16 01:11:00.535: E/PstContactCreator(549): file : import_tmp_0.vcf

02-16 01:11:00.535: I/PstContactCreator(549): Copy a Uri to app local storage 
(file:///cache/pst_contact_r.tmp -> import_tmp_0.vcf)

02-16 01:11:00.535: I/PstContactCreator(549): dcshin 111

02-16 01:11:00.535: E/PstContactCreator(549): inputChannel : 
java.nio.channels.Channels$InputStreamChannel@414d6ca8

02-16 01:11:00.535: I/PstContactCreator(549): dcshin 222

02-16 01:11:00.535: W/ApplicationContext(549): Unable to create files directory files

02-16 01:11:00.545: E/PstContactCreator(549): destUri : file:/import_tmp_0.vcf

02-16 01:11:00.545: I/PstContactCreator(549): dcshin 333

02-16 01:11:00.545: E/PstContactCreator(549): getPackageName : android

02-16 01:11:00.545: E/PstContactCreator(549): getPackageCodePath : null

02-16 01:11:00.545: E/PstContactCreator(549): getPackageResourcePath : null

02-16 01:11:00.545: W/ApplicationContext(549): Unable to create files directory files

02-16 01:11:00.545: E/PstContactCreator(549): java.lang.NullPointerException

02-16 01:11:00.545: I/PstContactCreator(549): Finished caching vCard.

02-16 01:11:00.545: I/PstManagerService(549): onsetrecordcmd start

02-16 01:11:00.545: I/PstManagerService(549): f.exists

02-16 01:11:00.555: I/PstManagerService(549): after creteNewFile

02-16 01:11:00.555: W/PstContactCreator(549): pst contact start!

02-16 01:11:00.555: E/PstContactCreator(549): filename : import_tmp_0.vcf

02-16 01:11:00.555: W/ApplicationContext(549): Unable to create files directory files

02-16 01:11:00.555: E/PstContactCreator(549): file : import_tmp_0.vcf

02-16 01:11:00.555: I/PstContactCreator(549): Copy a Uri to app local storage 
(file:///cache/pst_contact_r.tmp -> import_tmp_0.vcf)

02-16 01:11:00.555: I/PstContactCreator(549): dcshin 111

02-16 01:11:00.555: E/PstContactCreator(549): inputChannel : 
java.nio.channels.Channels$InputStreamChannel@41a20ff8

02-16 01:11:00.555: I/PstContactCreator(549): dcshin 222

02-16 01:11:00.555: W/ApplicationContext(549): Unable to create files directory files

02-16 01:11:00.555: E/PstContactCreator(549): destUri : file:/import_tmp_0.vcf

02-16 01:11:00.555: I/PstContactCreator(549): dcshin 333

02-16 01:11:00.555: E/PstContactCreator(549): getPackageName : android

02-16 01:11:00.555: E/PstContactCreator(549): getPackageCodePath : null

02-16 01:11:00.555: E/PstContactCreator(549): getPackageResourcePath : null

02-16 01:11:00.555: W/ApplicationContext(549): Unable to create files directory files

02-16 01:11:00.555: E/PstContactCreator(549): java.lang.NullPointerException

02-16 01:11:00.555: I/PstContactCreator(549): Finished caching vCard.

02-16 01:11:00.565: I/DiagJNIInterface(1791): Going to send message

02-16 01:11:00.565: D/ShutdownThread(549): Notifying thread to start shutdown 
longPressBehavior=1
02-16 01:11:00.615: I/ShutdownThread(549): Sending shutdown broadcast...

Answer (score 0):

FIrst check your android manifest file. In permissions you should add  WRITE_EXTERNAL:storage 
or the permissions to WRITE Contacts. that I saw you're dealing to

Comment: My source is framework. context.getPackageName() = android. framework need permission, too?

Comment: no it doesn't need permissions I think, can you post your new catlog, to have a better Idea of which errors still there

Comment: I don't know, how to post. Logcat added.

Comment: on your initial post click on Edit and repost your LOGCAT

Answer (score 0):

Your app has package name of `android`? That's wrong. Change it to something like `com.yourname`.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue (NullPointerException looked to be coming from from openFileOutput), where I had created a java class without first passing in the Context.

```
getApplicationContext().openFileOutput(FILENAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

Didn't work, (even though compiles fine) so I changed it to the below. (Note ctx.openFileOutput.

```
public ClassName(Context ctx){
    FileOutputStream fos;
    try {
        fos = ctx.openFileOutput(FILENAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        fos.write(("Date created: " + SimpleDateFormat.getDateInstance().format(now) + "\n").getBytes());
        fos.close();
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Whilst this may not address your issue, I'll put it here in case it helps others.